# Setting for Cookies never expire in SailsJs

Tags: cookies, sails.js, session-cookies

I'm developing one application that i need a infinit session for some login. But my session was expire. I'm using Redis for control sessions and i'm authenticate Users with Json Web Token. 
Apparently, my Cookies settings is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Open config/session.js

Uncomment the following lines:

```
cookie: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
},
```

Replace maxAge value with some that will point in distant future, like 10 years from now:

```
maxAge: 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```